# Create a macro for vim paste management

Tags: vim

I would like to create a macro that does:

```
set paste
<paste>
set nopaste
```

This will save me from `<paste>` (Oh, forgot I again!) Delete. Execute the above.  Over and over.  :-)

But I can't think of a way to do it because  action comes from outside of vi.  I am using iTerm2 on a mac.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're pasting from the clipboard, paste directly using `"+p`. I use `\p` as a mapping for it:

```
nnoremap <leader>p "+p
```

This should prevent problems with indentation, etc.

I have the following mappings for pasting from the clipboard and copying to it:

```
noremap <leader>p "+p
noremap <leader>y "+y
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remap your paste command to <kbd>LEADER + p</kbd>

```
nnoremap <leader>p :set paste<cr>p:set nopaste<cr>
```